# Open Notepad, Paste Text in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, shell, copy-paste

I want to open Notepad  from Silverlight and then paste some text into it. I was able to use the clipboard method to move the text I want to the clipboard. Then I use shell to open notepad. The final step is to paste the contents of the clipboard into notepad. This can be done by the user pressing Ctrl-V or Edit – Paste

However, this is an unsatisfactory solution.  I’d like to automate the last step, pasting the clipboard into notepad.

Here is my code:

```
 System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(l_StringBuilder.ToString)


                ' next open notepad
  OpenShell("notepad.exe")


  System.Windows.Clipboard.GetText() ‘ this does not work


    Private Sub OpenShell(p_Program As String)
        Try
            If (AutomationFactory.IsAvailable) Then
                Dim shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application")


                shell.ShellExecute(p_Program) 'Open notepad

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in another forum. Here is the link to it:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/b787244d-a0a9-4aea-8858-e94644742ff0/#05ca684e-1d22-4bca-a207-9c422a7cf5d6